# Dictionary function to find the key,value pair with least value

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

How to print the cheapest item in the dictionary when the dictionary consists of keys and values as items and their prices?
I tried using operator function for sorting but it converts the dictionary to tuple and then i am unable to display the dictionary key/value.
is there any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `min` with the dictionary's `.items()`, and pass the value of the pair to sort against.

```
>>> data = {'foo': 17.5, 'bar': 5.8, 'abc': 12.6}
>>> min(data.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
('bar', 5.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are your answers:

**Novice way:**

```
shoes_list = {'adidas':1000, 'Nike':3000, 'local': 100}

cheapest = ""

for key in shoes_list:
    if cheapest == "" or shoes_list[cheapest] > shoes_list[key]:
        cheapest = key
print(cheapest)
```

**Intermediate:**

```
shoes_list = {'adidas':1000, 'Nike':3000, 'local': 100}
Cheapest = min(shoes_list, key=shoes_list.get)
print(Cheapest)
```

**Most efficient way:**

```
import operator
shoes_list = {'adidas':1000, 'Nike':3000, 'local': 100}
print(min(shoes_list.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> data = {'foo': 17.5, 'bar': 5.8, 'abc': 12.6}

>>> min_val = min(data.values())
>>> {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v == min_val}
{'bar': 5.8}
```

However, CoryKramer's only iterates over the dictionary once, whereas my answer needs two runs

Answer (score 0):

```
#1) Convert the dictionary values into list,find the minimum
#2) Find the index value of the minimum value.
#3) Finally convert the list value to strings and  print it.
#SOURCE CODE

    dd={'mobile1':10000, 'mobile2':11000, 'mobile3':13000, 'mobile4':9000, 'mobile5':15000, 'mobile6':16000, 'mobile7':17000, 'mobile8':18000, 'mobile9':19000}
    k=list(dd.values())
    d={}
    def get_key(val): 
        for key, value in dd.items(): 
             if val == value: 
                 return key 
    
    mm=k[0]
    for i in range(1,len(k)):
        if k[i]<mm:
            mm=k[i]
    l=mm
    index_value = list(dd.keys()).index(get_key(l)) 
    f=list(list(dd.items())[index_value])
    print(str(f[0])+":"+str(f[1]))
```